# MAC Textedit to PHP Encoding Displays Wired Characters

Tags: php, regex, macos, encoding

```
MAC Text:          Hypertension, Stage 1 - Systolic 140-159 or diastolic 90-99
                                                       |                   |
WINDOWS/HTML Text: Hypertension, Stage 1 - Systolic 140Ð159 or diastolic 90Ð99
```

I am using below code for conversion hyphen sign but this above and other characters are not displaying from mac text to HTML output and sometime generates wired characters like `Â , â€, ™s, Â , â€, ™s, Â , â€, ™s, Â , â€, ™s`.

```
$content = "Hypertension, Stage 1 - Systolic 140Ð159 or diastolic 90Ð99";
$content =  iconv(mb_detect_encoding($content, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $content);
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding( $content, "auto" );
$content = str_replace( "?", "[question_mark]", $content );
$content = mb_convert_encoding( $content, $target_encoding, $encoding);
$content = str_replace( "?", "", $content );
$content = str_replace( "[question_mark]", "?", $content );
echo $content;
```

This was not possible to convert after this I am trying this code for manually change wired characters also, below code also not finding wired characters and not sometimes reads non wired characters.

```
$content = "Hypertension, Stage 1 - Systolic 140Ð159 or diastolic 90Ð99";
$content = html_entity_decode($content, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
preg_match_all('/[^\x20-\x7f][^!-]/', $content, $badwords);
print_r($badwords[0]);
```

Comment: Is `content` loaded from an external resource in the real code?

Comment: yes, content comes from mac text files and i read using PHP and using windows system it generates problematic also, php can't read proper characters it converts wired characters.